# How to read cookie in nsIChannel?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

```
const {Cc,Ci,Cr} = require("chrome");
function TracingListener() {
//this.receivedData = [];
}
function CCIN(cName, ifaceName) {
return Cc[cName].createInstance(Ci[ifaceName]);
}
function CCSV(cName, ifaceName){
    if (Cc[cName])
        // if fbs fails to load, the error can be _CC[cName] has no properties
        return Cc[cName].getService(Ci[ifaceName]);
};
TracingListener.prototype =
{
originalListener: null,
receivedData: null,   // array for incoming data.

onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count)
{
    this.originalListener.onDataAvailable(request, context,inputStream, offset, count);
},

onStartRequest: function(request, context) {
    this.receivedData = [];
    this.originalListener.onStartRequest(request, context);

//thechannel.setRequestHeader("X-Hello", "World", false);
//this part of code will stop the request
    /*request.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
var cookie=request.getRequestHeader("Cookie");
console.log("cookie="+cookie);*/
var postText = this.readPostTextFromRequest(request, context);
console.log("postText="+postText111);
},

onStopRequest: function(request, context, statusCode)
{
//this part of code will successfullly print the cookie
    /*request.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
var cookie=request.getRequestHeader("Cookie");
console.log("cookie="+cookie);*/
    this.originalListener.onStopRequest(request, context, statusCode);
},

QueryInterface: function (aIID) {
    if (aIID.equals(Ci.nsIStreamListener) ||
        aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports)) {
        return this;
    }
    throw Cr.NS_NOINTERFACE;
},
readPostTextFromRequest : function(request, context) {
    try
    {
        var is = request.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIUploadChannel).uploadStream;
        if (is)
        {
            var ss = is.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISeekableStream);
            var prevOffset;
            if (ss)
            {
                prevOffset = ss.tell();
                ss.seek(Ci.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);
            }

            // Read data from the stream..
            var charset = "UTF-8";
            var text = this.readFromStream(is, charset, true);

            // Seek locks the file so, seek to the beginning only if necko hasn't read it yet,
            // since necko doesn't seek to 0 before reading (at lest not till 459384 is fixed).
            if (ss && prevOffset == 0) 
                ss.seek(Ci.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);

            return text;
        }
        else {
            //dump("Failed to Query Interface for upload stream.\n");
        }
    }
    catch(exc)
    {
        //dumpError(exc);
    }

    return null;
},
readFromStream : function(stream, charset, noClose) {

    var sis = CCSV("@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1", "nsIBinaryInputStream");
    sis.setInputStream(stream);

    var segments = [];
    for (var count = stream.available(); count; count = stream.available())
        segments.push(sis.readBytes(count));

    if (!noClose)
        sis.close();

    var text = segments.join("");
    return text;
}

}


hRO = {

observe: function(request, aTopic, aData){
    try {

        if (aTopic == "http-on-examine-response") {
            request.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);

            //if (request.originalURI && piratequesting.baseURL == request.originalURI.prePath && request.originalURI.path.indexOf("/index.php?ajax=") == 0) {
                var newListener = new TracingListener();
                request.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel);
                newListener.originalListener = request.setNewListener(newListener);
            //}
        } 
    } catch (e) {
        /*dump("\nhRO error: \n\tMessage: " + e.message + "\n\tFile: " + e.fileName + "  line: " + e.lineNumber + "\n");*/
    }
},

QueryInterface: function(aIID){

    if (aIID.equals(Ci.nsIObserver) ||
    aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports)) {
        return this;
    }

    throw Cr.NS_NOINTERFACE;

},
};


var observerService = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
.getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);

observerService.addObserver(hRO,
"http-on-examine-response", false);
```

My question is: the same lines of code:

```
request.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
var cookie=request.getRequestHeader("Cookie");
console.log("cookie="+cookie);
```

performs different results in onStartRequest and onStopRequest, why? 
I can read the cookie in onStopRequest but fails in onStartRequest. I don't think the request is not ready in onStartRequest because I can read the postText in onStartRequest.

Comment: See here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/1e6ab66a09b3c32ed49f this does what you need, it reads the cookies. And it does it in similar way to what you are doing. It's messy code though did this long long ago. But it works.